# Why div is repeating with same id and class after postback in partial view, MVC

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am having issues in rendering partial view after post back, functionality is working fine but div which is the partial view is repeating after post back. 
Here is my code for the View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MarkDefiniteDischargePatient", "PDDD",new { },
                 new AjaxOptions
                 {
                    OnSuccess = "onSuccess",
                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                    UpdateTargetId = "div_DefiniteDischarge"
                 },
                 new 
                 { 
                   @name = "DefiniteDischargeForm", 
                   @id = "frmDefiniteDischarge" }
                 ))
{
 Html.RenderPartial("DefiniteDischargePartial", Model);
}
```

I have separate Partial View which has div with id div_DefiniteDischarge in it. I have attached screenshot of my console for the reference. How to get rid off this extra div?

[image: Repeated div screenshot]

Comment: You should have only one `div` with `id="div_DefiniteDischarge"` in the main view, not in the partial your loading in the `Ajax.BeginForm`

Comment: Okay let me try this

Comment: It should work.remove duplicate div with `id="div_DefiniteDischarge"`

Comment: <div id="div_DefiniteDischarge" class="div-right">
@Html.RenderPartial("DefiniteDischargePartial", Model);
</div>

If I do this way its giving me error: Cannot implicitly convert void to object 
And i remove @ sign then its showing plain text

Comment: @Parth Trivedi -  I have not given duplicate id, I just gave it in partial view page not in the main page I am just updating this div after postback.

Comment: Try to put `Ajax.BeginForm` inside `partial view` and put `div` outside `partial view`

Comment: Okay let me try this

Comment: I put div outside of Ajax.BeginForm  in Main page but why css is losing after postback for that Partial View

Comment: Yes you have done perfectly. Check Have you written `Partial View` from `Controller` after postback?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100444/discussion-between-mahrukh-mehmood-and-parth-trivedi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `Ajax.BeginForm` inside partial view and put div outside `partial view`

Also check have you included

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```